# y.tab.c and y.tab.h files are not generated on win64

Tags: yacc, lex

I ran the following command in the Windows command prompt:

`yacc -d calci.y`

After successful execution it generates 2 files: `calci.tab.c`  and `calci.tab.h`. But it should have generated `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`.

I am very new to `lex` and `yacc`, so I do not have an idea about the error.

Also, it gives me the following error when I try to run command:

> cc lex.yy.c calci.tab.c -o out.exe:
>
> error: calci.l:3:23: fatal error: y.tab.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

Please give some suggestion.

**yacc program:--->>**

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%token INTEGER

%%

program:
        program expr '\n'         { printf("%d\n", $2); }
        | 
        ;

expr:
        INTEGER
        | expr '+' expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr '-' expr           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

**lex program:-->>>>**

```
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%%

[0-9]+      {
                yylval = atoi(yytext);
                return INTEGER;
            }

[-+\n]      { return *yytext; }

[ \t]       ;       /* skip whitespace */

.           yyerror("Unknown character");

%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just accept that bison will name its output files based on the name of its input file.

Creating files called `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h` is the legacy behaviour of the original yacc tool; with current `bison` versions, you can achieve compatible behaviour by supplying the `-y` command-line option to `bison`. But I don't recommend doing that for new code; it will also change some details of the parser's behaviour in order to be legacy-compatible, and if you don't have legacy code those behaviours may not be desirable.

Basing the names of the bison-generated files on the input files makes it possible to have more than one bison source file in the same directory. If you don't want to use the name of the source file, you can specify an explicit output file name with the `-o` option (and the `--defines` option if you want the header file's name to have a different prefix than the source file).

All that means you need to change the name of the file being included into the lexer, so the line will become

```
#include "calci.tab.h"
```

(assuming you don't use the `-o`/`--defines` options.)

Comment: Or use the `-y` option.